# why the CPU utilization and other indicators collected by glances are larger than those collected?

Tags: python, cpu, utilization

can anyone explain why the CPU utilization and other indicators collected by glances are larger than those collected by the task manager or the top command?

Collect the CPU utilization of the same process within the same time range and find that the value collected by glances will be larger.

Comment: You're talking about https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/ ?  IDK if that's really a programming question, since it's not about writing code. OTOH, perhaps there's a question of what APIs it uses to gather info?  Still, seems like probably a better fit on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks，I learned that Glances uses psuntil in python to collect indicators, so I would like to ask why the indicator data collected by Glances is too large.

Comment: How much too large?  Like 8x higher?  Or like 0.05 higher?  Could it be explained by the load of running Glances itself?

Comment: After doing a benchmark test, the CPU utilization output by psutil was 55%, and the result using a PowerShell script combined with Windows Performance Counters was 6%. The difference is nearly 10 times.

Comment: Oh, you're on Windows?  How many cores does your system have?  8 or 10?  On Windows, 1.0 is all cores busy.  On Linux (and perhaps with Glances), 1.0 load is one core busy, 55% is about half of one core busy. 800% would be all cores busy on an 8-core system.